# Orchard Custom Module Development and Git

Tags: git, orchardcms

So, I started some custom module development and now i find myself trying to keep it all tidy.
I have a branch from a cloned version of the lastest Orchard, [localdev]. 
Then, i created another branch for my custom module. lets called it [sitemap].
 
Went to the Solution and created a module through the command prompt called 'sitemap' and worked on it. 
Now, i want to have a standalone repository in sync with the module and perhaps upload to my github. 
 
How can this be achieved? 
Should i do it in a different order?
 
Ta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a repository for your module's folder. It really is that simple.

Comment: I do not know what i was thinking. nice one.